Angular local library component rendering error (reading 'bindingStartIndex')
I've got a thing to discuss on Angular 12/13.
I'm not a huge frontend hero, and have never dealed with own angular libraries, so may be I'm asking stupid questions, so sorry, but..
Here (github) a simple example of what I am trying to do.
I have a bunch of components to be shared across several applications. All these apps are currently in a single repository. So I created a library and now trying to reuse it in my app.
The thing is that as we're in a single repo, and I can see no reason to post this lib as a package and install it back from npm, and to be honest wouldn't like to deal with it now. So, I decided on referencing my lib using "file: {path}" approach.
And this the place where an adventure started.
First it was a problem to get no error on lib's components, and it took time and all the power of AI (who gave me contraversional answers, but whatever) to finally figure out that I should have
this
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": ["../my-lib/projects/my-lib/src/lib/my-lib.module.ts"]
    }

in tsconfig.json
and this
    "my-lib": "file:../my-lib/dist/my-lib"

in
package.json
I'm noticing this because I'm not sure if it's really correct thing, but at least it makes things look kind of working.
Now I have another problem. My lib component and it's twin in app behave differently and lib one fails with such message:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
'bindingStartIndex')

here is the error in the console
I implemented two identical components tow see the difference.
Updated angular from 12 to 13 version.
I had dug into core debug and sort out that both components are present in main.js and are compiled identically, but rendering lib component ends up with this error, while seems like app component rendering doesn't even come to this place while rendres fine. Then after a couple of days I gave up.
So, what a little bit of magic am I missing here?

This article really helped me solve this.
I moved the lib folder inside the app folder. Them followed these steps.
cd my-app
npm install
cd my-lib
npm install
npm run build
cd ../
npm link my-lib
npm link my-lib/dist/my-lib

After this you need to run build --watch on the library path and on another window, npm run start.
The fix that solved the "Cannot read property 'bindingStartIndex' of null"
Was to add preserveSymlinks to true in the angular.json
    ...
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        ...

Github Repo

adding "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"] to the paths of tsconfig.json did the trick.
Not sure if I'd ever find it out on my own.
